# Android - cannot call cordova plugin multiple times

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, plugins

I've this strange problem with a custom cordova 3.5.0 plugin in Android.
The first time I call the plugin, the callback is correctly executed; then if I load another page that has the same javascript plugin imported, if I call the plugin again, the callback is not called at all.
The java code is all executed with no problem, I get no error, simply the callback is not called. The curious thing is that if I remain in the same page, or go to a page where the javascript plugin is not imported and then return to the first page, the plugin works perfectly.

The callback is called as simpy as possible:

```
callback.success(0);
```

I've read that a solution could be to keep the callback, so I changed the code like this:

```
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0);
result.setKeepCallback(true);
callback.sendPluginResult(result);
```

But there was no change.

The plugin is called this way:

```
uploadFiles: function (successCallback, errorCallback, serviceUrl, arrayRes, requestObject) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback,
        errorCallback, 
        "Multipart",  // java class, service
        "uploadFiles", // action
        [{                 // and this array of custom arguments to create our entry
            "serviceUrl": serviceUrl,
            "resPaths": arrayRes,
            "requestObject": requestObject
        }]
    );
}
```

The javascript file is imported this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/mypackagename.multipart/multipart.js"></script>
```

Finally, the plugin is declared in config.xml like this:

```
 <feature name="Multipart" >
    <param
        name="android-package"
        value="mypackagename.plugins.MultipartPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

The code of plugin is this:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {   

    try {
        String requestURL = null;
        JSONArray resPaths = null;
        JSONObject requestObject = null;
        JSONObject argObject = args.getJSONObject(0);

        requestURL = argObject.getString("serviceUrl");
        resPaths = argObject.getJSONArray("resPaths");
        requestObject = argObject.getJSONObject("requestObject");

        String[] paths = new String[resPaths.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < resPaths.length(); i++)
            paths[i] = resPaths.getString(i).toString();

        CommunicationHelper.sendMultipartRequest(requestURL, requestObject,
            paths, new ResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject request,
                        JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED: " + response);
                    callbackContext.success(response);
                };

                @Override
                public void onError(JSONObject request, JSONObject response) {
                    callbackContext.error(0);
                }
            });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        callbackContext.error(0);
    }
    return true;
}

public static void sendMultipartRequest(final String url,
        final JSONObject request, final String[] resPaths,
        final ResponseHandler handler) {        

    new AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

            // create the multipart and make the request
            return response;            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

            if (handler != null) {
                if (result == null || result.has(ERROR))
                    handler.onError(request, result);
                else
                    handler.onSuccess(request, result);

                handler.onComplete();
            }
        }

    }.execute(request);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've found this solution that can bypass the problem, but does not solve it at all.

In the javascript plugin I declare and add to window the successCallback and errorCallback functions:

```
window.MultipartuploadFilesSuccessCallback = successCallback;
window.MultipartuploadFilesErrorCallback = errorCallback;
```

The name is simply PLUGIN_NAME + ACTION + SuccessCallback/ErrorCallback, than in the Java plugin I do this:

```
((CordovaActivity) cordova.getActivity()).sendJavascript(PLUGIN_NAME + action + "SuccessCallback(" + result.toString() + ");");
((CordovaActivity) cordova.getActivity()).sendJavascript(PLUGIN_NAME + action + "ErrorCallback(" + result.toString() + ");");
```

I repeat, it works and can be generalized, but it is not very elegant.

Comment: The issue is most likely in your native code. Without seeing it my guess is that there is a static reference to the callbackContext that is only valid for the first context. So when new instances are called they are still calling back to the original context. Can you show the parts of your native code that deal with the callbackContext?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon: good point, I added the code of the plugin... if that is the issue, is there any other way to call the success?